# Вызвать функцию контроллера средствами JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, функции, controller

Как вызвать функцию контроллера с параметром средствами JavaScript в Laravel 5. Никак не получается и все!

Controller:

```
public function archive($id)
{
  $article = Article::find($id);

  $article->public = 0;
  $article->featured = 0;
  $article->archive = 1;

  $article->save();
}
```

И прилагающийся роут:

```
Route::post('/archive/{id}', 'HomeController@archive');
```

JS:

```
$('.change').click(function(){

$.ajax({
  'url':'/archive/2',
  'method':'POST',
  headers: {
     'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
})
})
```

И кнопка:

```
<button type="button" title="Изменить" class="change">Изменить</button>
```

Буду благодарен ЛЮБЫМ рабочим вариантам. Спасибо!

Comment: пошлите ajax запрос c методом POST на урл '/archive/{id}', где id - это ид вышей статьи, если исользовать jquery `$.ajax({'url':'/archive/'+id,'method':'POST',succes:function(){}}) `

Comment: В том то и дело , что ajax возвращает success а вот данные до контроллер не доходят и непонятно почему. Именно из этого возник вопрос

Comment: покажите ваш js и пожалуйста сделай `return response($article)`  в контроллере, что б быть уверенным что вы туда стучитесь

Comment: По вашему совету, сделал так 
`<button type="button" title="Изменить" onclick="$.ajax({'url':'/archive/2' ,'method':'POST',succes:function‌​(){}})">Изменить</button>`. В итоге консоль говорит `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Попробовал так `<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` и `'_token': $('#token').val()`, в итоге консоль говорит `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: так говорит потому что ваш контроллер, ничего не возвращает вы сделали в нем `return response($article) `

Comment: Да, но я все же получаю `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Ну так токен в data положите при отправке ajax запроса

Comment: Положил. Теперь при нажатии на кнопку вообще ничего не происходит. И консоль молчит, и функция не вызывается

Comment: Пожалуйста отредактируй свой вопрос, и поставь свою функцию js как она есть сейчас, в отредактированном виде

Comment: $('.change').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:'/archive/2',
  method:'POST',
  data:{"_token":$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}, success: function(data){console.log(data)}, error: function(data){console.log(data)}
})
})

Comment: Если продолжит выпендриваться зайдите в Kernal и закоменте \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class

Answer (score 1):

Нет ничего удивительного тут. Вы используете метод POST, как метод GET.
Думаю, что вас смутило, что в примерах в рунете часто используют пример с post.
Но там post - это не метод POST, а просто название переменной.

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId)
```

В вашем случае, я бы использовал метод GET. Т.к. у вас все от этого метода в примере.

Но если вам все же так хочется использовать POST, то придется его переписать. Как аякс-запрос, так и контроллер. Роут тоже.

Как то так:

контроллер:

```
  public function archive(Request $request){
     $request->id;
  };
```

аякс:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: POST,
  data: {id: 2},
  jsonp: 'callback',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    callback.call(this, data);
  },
  error: function(data) {
  }
});
```

роут:

```
Route::post('archive', 'HomeController@archive');
```